# Test data generator for MySQL

Tags: command-line, mysql, sql

I want a tool for populating a MySQL database with random data.

- The data generated for the primary and secondary keys should be coherent, so the data will not cause integrity errors.
- It should provide a way to create rules about how to generate data for the fields. For example, choose from a list of words, or just create a random alphanumeric text.
- It should be really simple to install and use. It must not be part of a bigger application with a lot of features which have nothing to do with data generation.

It must work from the command line. In this use case, a nice UI for configure the application is not useful.

Bonus: it will be great if it's open source.

Comment: FYI, similar Question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3060169/642706

Comment: Hi @BasilBourque. It's similar, but not the same. In this case, to be free is optional (I know that Open Source is not the same than free, please don't kill me). The important thing is it should use rules, work from the command line, etc.

Comment: I was merely pointing out existing info already posted online that might be useful here. The Question is inappropriate on that site and was closed. This Question here is appropriate and should be answered fully.

Comment: @BasilBourque Got it. I was just a little nervous about have my question closed because it was asked before. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this question before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608438/how-can-i-populate-my-databases-all-tables-with-random-data!

I found that [filldb.info](http://filldb.info/) seems to works well.

Main Database Data Generator Features:

- List item
- Generate Unique Values
- Generate Optional Values
- Foreign Key support (multiple tables)
- Numeric values (integer numbers, float numbers etc)
- Paragraphs and Sentences
- Date and time values
- Emails, domains, ip,user agents
- Images, files, extensions, mimeTypes
- User data (firstnames, lastnames, title, gender)
- Locations (countries, cities, address, languages)
- Boolean values
- Credit cards
- Hashed data, barcodes, uuid

And all that is done online through their form-based UI in 3 steps:

- Submit database schema
- Generate data for database tables
- Export Database with generated data

Comment: I've also heard of http://www.gedis-studio.com/gedis-online.html but I haven't tried yet. I've also heard people are using visual studio for that: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2190/generating-sql-server-test-data-with-visual-studio-2010/.

Comment: Also, I've seen other people use the community edition of APEXSQL https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_generate.aspx.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but looks like all of those tools work using a website or a UI, and the idea is that the tool must work from the command line.

Comment: @François Link-only Answers are not welcome on a Stack Exchange site. Please summarize the pros and cons of the products listed on the linked site, and explain their relevance in the context of the specifics of this Question.

Comment: @basil-bourque, edited, thanks. I just didn't have much time when answering but yet didn't want to lose the answer so I thought an answer stub is better than no answer.

Comment: Oh, actually, the question got edited since my first answer....

Comment: @François It still doesn't answer the question. It's a website.